# Remove all the characters before the last comma in R

Tags: r

I have a data table like this:

```
id       number
1        5562,4024,...,1213 
2        4244,4214,...,244
3        424,4213
4        1213,441
...
```

And I want to subset only the last part of each column of number, which should be like:

```
id       number
1        1213
2        244
3        4213
4        441
...
```

So what should I do to achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is capture the digits at the end (`$`) of the string as a group that follows a `,` and replace with the backreference (`\\1`) of the captured group

```
df$number <- as.numeric(sub(".*,(\\d+)$", "\\1", df$number))
```

---

Or match the characters (`.*`) until the `,` and replace it with blank (`""`)

```
df$number <- as.numeric(sub(".*,", "", df$number))
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(id = 1:4, number = c("5562,4024,...,1213", 
    "4244,4214,...,244", 
"424,4213", "1213,441")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
 -4L))
```

Comment: Yes, it works, the second one is very easy to understand, thank you!